# How many distinct trees with N nodes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I need help on this question regarding how many distinct trees exist given N nodes in the tree. "Distinct" here means that two isomorphic trees are counted as one. For 3 nodes, would the number of trees be 1 (since every other tree with 3 nodes is just an isomorphism of the other)?

Thanks.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A116380  -  recurrent formula

Answer (score 2):

The number of trees on $n$ nodes is given in https://oeis.org/A000055. There’s no closed-form formula for this, though.

While this answer’s sequence looks like the others for the first five to ten values, they quickly begin to differ. This is the one that counts all (unrooted) trees up to graph isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your problem according to Cayley-Sylvester theorem is $n$ in the power of $n-2$.

Comment: Also, this is wrong, because the $n^{n-2}$ formula distinguishes isomorphic trees with differently labeled vertices.

Answer (score 0):

I think isomorphism needs to be better defined here. If we label the nodes A, B, and C, A-B-C is clearly the same as C-B-A, but A-C-B is a relabeling, which may or may not be considered an isomorphism. If we don't label nodes at all, and the tree is non-directed, then yes, every 3-node tree is equivalent.

In this latter case, I'm unsure, but perhaps you can look at the problem as counting the number of distinct Steiner trees with 1-N vertices: https://oeis.org/A104653?